# Wrong php launched for <?php directive embedded in HTML

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php

On my laptop (osx 10.2.2) , i brewed apache 2.4.12 and php 5.5.22, with php-fpm. Strangely, when i ping on the server for a .php file, apache binds properly to the new php and runs that. If however, there is an `embedded` php command in a html file, (like below), php 5.5.22 reverts when interpreting the following html file and launches the distribution php (5.5.14)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include_once("sysinfo.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

what gives ? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because Apache doesn’t look inside files when deciding whether to proxy a request to PHP-FPM or process it internally. `.html` files are not sent to PHP-FPM, although it could be configured that way. Waste of performance, though.

IMHO, executing PHP in files *not* named `.php`, `.phtml` or whatever is a misconfiguration. One would expect HTML files to be truly static. If you’re using PHP-FPM you should probably disable mod_php.

Comment: I undestand it is 'bad form' , but i am prepping locally on my dev box to 'accept' the gift of a partner's software solution onto my servers (all cranked up and running with php-fpm). I am just trying to find a migration/mitigation method for the stuff i am about to be pushing to prod :(

Comment: Ok, figured it out, accepting this answer as you pointed me in the right direction.